# error in reading session variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using Sessions in Cakephp . I am having 3 controllers .In the User controller while logged in , i have wrote the User id in the Session variable .

But when i try to read it in the other controller i am getting the value of the Session variable.WHy so???

Edit :

In my users controller

i am writing the User id of the person who have logged in as

```
   function login()
   {


    $this->Session->write('userId',$this->User->loginUser($this->data));
    $this->User->data=$this->data;

    if (!$this->User->validates())
        {
            $this->Flash('Please enter valid inputs','/main' );
            return; 
        }
    if($this->Session->read('userId')>0){

                    $this->Session->setFlash('Login Successful');
        $this->redirect('/main/home');
        break;

    }
    else{
        $this->flash('Username and password do not match.','/main');

    }

}
```

And in my forms controller i am trying to read the session variable user id like..,

```
  <?php
  class FormsController extends AppController 
  {

var $name = 'Forms';
var $helpers=array('Html','Ajax','Javascript','Form');
var $components = array( 'RequestHandler','Autocomplete');
var $uses=array('Form','User','Attribute','Result','Invite','Share','Choice');


 function index() {}


     function design() 
     {
            $userId=$this->Session->read('userId');echo $userId;
            $this->data['Form']['created_by']=$this->Session->read('userId');

            $userName=$this->Form->findUserName($this->data);
            $this->set('userName',$userName);
     }
}
```

But this User id is not displaying the session variable what i have wrote....

Why its happening..

Comment: Can you post any code...? Are you using the Cake Auth functions or rolled your own...?

Comment: i have added the code to the Post

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to look into using the Cake built-in [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication) if you haven't already.
2. Have you actually tested the return value of `$this->User->loginUser()`?
3. Can you save anything else in the Session at all?
4. See if you can get any hints out of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226426/problem-with-session-variable).